# Using gradle for a flat, multi-module project where settings.gradle is not the highest-level dependency

Tags: gradle

I have a multi-module project with a directory structure like:

```
proj
|-modA
|-modB
|-modMain
\-modSysTest
```

The dependencies are:

```
modB -> modA
modMain -> modB
modMain -> modA
modSysTest -> modMain
```

We currently use Ant as our build system.  Every module has a build.xml.  There is a master.xml that runs the multi-module build, which is in modMain.

I am investigating switching our project to use gradle.  I can get a multi-module build working if I put a build.gradle and settings.gradle in a new sibling directory and set up the dependent modules using includeFlat.

I tried moving the gradle files into modMain, which is the home of both the main component of our system as well as the top-level build script (master.xml) that builds the whole system, but I cannot get the build working this way.  My main stumbling block at the moment is trying to configure modSysTest to depend on modMain from within modMain.

Here is the settings.gradle from modMain:

```
includeFlat 'modA', 'modB', 'modSysTest'
```

Here is the build.gradle file from modMain:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    };
    dependencies {
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    }
}

project(':modB') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':modA')
    }
}

project(':modSysTest') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':modMain')
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':modA'), project(':modB')
}
```

When using this configuration, I get the error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'modMain'.
> Project with path ':modMain' could not be found in project ':modSysTest'.
```

I am not sure how to specify modMain as a dependency for modSysTest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project path of the root project is `:`, not `:modMain`. It's not very customary (but possible) to have code in the root project. I don't see how putting `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` into a sibling directory of `modMain` would give a different result (unless you also changed the contents of `settings.gradle`). Note that with such a setup, Gradle won't find `settings.gradle` unless you start the build from the `modMain` directory or pass the location of the settings file with `-c`.

Comment: Maybe the point is to make it easier to import projects in Eclipse right? Like in Maven where you can point to the parent with ../ and all the modules can stay in the same flat structure.

Comment: It's already quite easy. Gradle needs to evaluate `settings.gradle` in order to find `build.gradle` files, so having the latter point to the former wouldn't help.

Comment: You're right, but thats a doubt that pleople studying Gradle usually have. You made a good point about `settings.gradle` not beeing found, tx.

Comment: I can't see how this answers the question.  Peter, you haven't said whether, or how, it is possible to retain a flat folder structure between dependencies in Gradle.  I have a use-case for this: developing multiple applications simultaneously, which share the same library code.  It is unwieldy to have multiple copies of those dependencies checked out for each application.  This seems like a common use case to be honest, and Maven supports it very well.  For Gradle not to seems kind of shocking.

Comment: @ChrisHatton Not sure what you are asking. Perhaps post a new question (after checking the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) and the samples in the `gradle-all` download).

Comment: Chris, if I understand correctly, you might need to place root project files to directory called "master", so gradle finds it automatically. If it has an arbitrary name like "modMain" it won't know where to look for settings.gradle file.